# Sails.JS association validation

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm using several one to many associations in Sails.JS that look like the following:

**User**

```
email: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
projects: {
    collection: 'project',
    via: 'user'
}
```

**Project**

```
name: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    minLength: 3,
    maxLength: 50
},
user: {
    model: 'user',
    required: true
},
sites: {
    collection: 'site',
    via: 'project'
}
```

**Site**

```
project: {
    model: 'project',
    required: true
},
name: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
}
```

Now when I fire off a POST request to /project it creates the project fine, and specifying the param 'user' (taken from the session) associates the project with that particular user.

The same goes for when I create a new site. However, I appear to be able to specify any number for the param 'project', even if that particular project ID doesn't exist. Really it should fail the validation if the project doesn't exist and not create the site. I thought it'd look up the association with project and check that the project ID specified is valid?

Also, I only want to be able to create a site that is associated with a project that belongs to the current user. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's a bug or intended behavior with your non-existent project ID association, but one work-around is to have a `beforeCreate` hook in your models to verify that the project ID exists:

```js
// In your Site model
beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
  ...
  var projectID = values['project'];
  Project.findOne(projectID, function (err, project) {
    if (err || !project) return next("some error message");
    return next();
  });
}
```

You can also do a check in the `beforeCreate` hook for your second question:

```js
// In your Site model
beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
  ...
  var projectID = values['project'];
  Project.findOne(projectID).populate('user').exec(function (err, project) {
    if (err || !project) return next("some error message");
    if (project.user.id != values['userID']) return next("some other error message");
    return next();
  });
}
```

Note that you'll have to pass 'userID' as a param into the params for creating a Site instance.